# passed command line paramenters

Tags: command-line, parameters

I'm writing a program where the user can pass in options such as, -e or -n, as command line parameters. But the following if loop doesn't work for some reason. I'm trying to run the program as: ./a.out -e test.html where test.html is the filename I'm parsing:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ifstream inf;
    if(argv[1] == "-e")
        cout << "do somethin" << endl;
  else
        cout << "do something different" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char**` instead of `char*` ?

Comment: Isn't that what its suppose to be? Changing it char* gives me a warning that it should be char**

Comment: "int main(int argc, char** argv)" or "int main(int argc, char** argv)" is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly comparing 2 strings.  Change your if()

```
if(argv[1] == "-e")
```

to

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0) {
```

Be sure to

```
#include <string.h>
```

Note: Although your code is C++ `cout << ...`, argv[1] is not a std:string, but s/b a `const char *`.  Thus `strcmp()` is need to compare it directly to a quoted string.  Alternatively you could:

```
#include <string>
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-e")  { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line to this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

1. It creates an array of argv
2. Each element of argv can hold a string of chars

I assumed your code to be a segment of something larger. But here's the complete code if you're not sure...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argv[1] == "-e")
        cout << "do somethin" << endl;
  else
        cout << "do something different" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```